# C++ char* by reference to C# string

Tags: c#, c++

Have a dll written in C++ that has char* reference values

`[functionName](parameter, out char*)`

When attempting to get value from C#, only receive the 1st character. Variable has a length of 5.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `out` in standard C++. The parameter would have to be either `char**` or `char*&` to be a valid reference-to-pointer.

```
functionName(parameter, char**)
functionName(parameter, char*&)
```

In any case, the only reason to pass a reference-to-pointer is if the function is going to set the pointer itself to memory that the function allocates. In C#, that would be best handled using a `ref IntPtr` or `out IntPtr` parameter, and then the C# code can use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` to access the `char` data.  The pointer (`IntPtr`) would have to be passed back to the DLL afterwards to release the allocated `char` data properly.

For example:

```cs
[DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = ..., EntryPoint = "...")]
int getData(parameter, out IntPtr ptr);

[DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = ..., EntryPoint = "...")]
void freeData(IntPtr ptr);

...

IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
int len = getData(parameter, out ptr);
string s = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr, len);
freeData(ptr);
```

Comment: what it is the default `CallingConvention` used if you don't precise it ? (` CallingConvention= CallingConvention.Cdecl`, ...)

Comment: @Landstalker [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention?view=netframework-4.8), the default `CallingConvention` for `DllImport` is `Winapi`, which is `StdCall` on Windows and `Cdecl` on Linux. If the DLL uses a different calling convention, you have to set the `CallingConvention` explicitly, eg: `[DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`.